# Installing Ruby 1.9.2 with RVM fails on OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-lion

I'm on Lion, I've installed xcode 4.1, and rvm version is 1.6.31 head

Here's what I did:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
```

The iconv dir points to the Brew install.

Here is [the output](https://raw.github.com/gist/1110214/ba9b909a0fd2c06c7c5e5395092a7d967d0a52d5/gistfile1.txt)

Here is [the make.log](https://raw.github.com/gist/1110221/9ba1ac25456585c2449a05037fe635404fe021bd/gistfile1.txt)

The error at the bottom of the make.log looks like it's trying to use the native libiconv instead of the one I specified:

```
ld: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64) for architecture x86_64
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When upgrading from 10.5 to 10.6 I had to nuke out all my installed source-built libraries and start over to fully resolve the 32-bit to 64-bit conversion issues. You may find you need to force-rebuild all of your brew packages.

Under MacPorts you just remove the `/opt` directory, salvaging any database files that might be in there first, and re-install everything again. I'm sure there's a similar procedure for Brew.

There's a way to alter the library load path, too, to set priority, but MacPorts does seem to handle this for you. `otool` can help diagnose which libraries are being loaded:

```
otool -L `which ruby`
```

Comment: I'm in the process of reinstalling my ports. Gettext wouldn't install, so I'm going the Brew route for that one.

Comment: I have this same problem but the ports had nothing to do with it (I cleaned and reinstalled everything). The problematic path is in /Developer and Ruby 1.9.2's and 1.9.3's configure scripts seem to be ignoring `--with-iconv-dir` (which is what RVM says to use for a custom iconv installation).

Answer (score 2):

- Remove RVM, thus making for a cleaner install later:

  $ RVM implode
- Remove XCode:

  $ sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

XCode is removed since in 4.2, at least, all references to gcc are linked to llvm-gcc (Apple's) own fork of gcc. llvm will NOT compile ruby.

(One can always re-install from the AppStore later)

- download and install GCC-10.7-v2.pkg from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads

This will install just the bare-bones GCC compiler. It can safely be overwritten by XCode if you decide to reinstall it, or simple removed using the same command as that used for removing XCode.

- reinstall RVM: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/
- Install the package manager "homebrew" from [Link](https://brew.sh/) and with it install libiconv.

  $ brew install libiconv

This will install several files to homebrew's home directory "/usr/local/cellar"

- backup /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib, and copy /usr/local/cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.2.dylib into it's place in /usr/local/lib

At this point you should have everything in place to install ruby 1.9.2 using RVM:

```
CC=gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14.1
```

(RVM does not actually support --with-iconv-dir, if you check the config.log file, but it might someday... in which case the copying of libiconv will be unnecessary)

Now go install gems and rails and anything else you might need.

Comment: `brew install libiconv` is no longer an option: Apple distributes libiconv with OS X, you can find it in /usr/lib.
Some build scripts fail to detect it correctly, please check existing
formulae for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby won't install with llvm, and gcc is now sym-linked to llvm.  The simple fix is to use

```
CC=gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.9.2-p290 --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.13.1
```

to force it to build with the real gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I find this incredibly difficult and prohibiting adoption of ruby 1.9. Surely the ruby guys can make this a no-brainer install?